# Doctrine: "1/1ReflectionException: Property Power\SelfBundle\Entity\Check::$part1 does not exists"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fatal-error

I am working with symfony. I have an entity `Check`. It has a relation field `part`.

The definition is something like:

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Power\SelfBundle\Entity\Friends", mappedBy="check")*/
protected $part1;
```

In the inverse relation (at `Friends`entity) the declaration is like:

```
/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Power\SelfBundle\Entity\Check", inversedBy="part1") */
public $check;
```

Now for removing ambiguity I have deleted the field and replaced it by `part`. I have updated the schema and cleared the cache and logs.

Later I am inserting into the friends entity (table infact) and it gives an error while event calling the entity:

`1/1ReflectionException: Property Power\SelfBundle\Entity\Check::$part1 does not exists`

But $part1 is deleted long ago. The `cache` is cleared and the `log` is cleared too. I have searched the whole project but nowhere even the text `part1` is found.

I am out of my wit!!

Can anyone please help me!!

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the current entity code, so we can look at this for errors.

Comment: @Lighthart - ok! if this is relevant - I am posting the code here.

Comment: You sure the `inversedBy` declaration has also been changed to 'part'? Not just the field name.

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás, Yes I have rechecked. I am updating the question with my entire entity code.

Comment: What does `console doctrine:schema:validate` report?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás, the output of the ``doctrine:schema:validate`` is as follows:

`code`
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
`code`

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás, I have fixed the problem. The problem was in doctrine metadata cache. 

In my config.yml ``metadata_cache_driver`` was set to use APC. So clearing the doctrine ``app/cache`` was not very helpful. 

After lots of searching - I have done

```php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"```

and BINGO it worked.

Comment: Very well. APC is very tricky. Accept your answer, so other people will find it.

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás, Thanks. SOF will let me accept my answer 15 hours later. :-)

Comment: Just so you know a simple apache restart will fix your APC issues next time, as that will also trigger an APC purge.

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás, I knew that actually and I tried that - but for some weird configuration in my system - it didn't worked. Thanks for the tips anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is fixed after lots of researching.

The problem was in doctrine metadata cache.

In my `config.yml` file `metadata_cache_driver` was set to use APC. So clearing the doctrine `app/cache` was not helpful.

After lots of searching - I have done

```
php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"
```

and BINGO it worked!!

So in my `config_dev.yml` I have overridden the setting to set the `metadata_cache_driver` to array.